# Default android application for a Tablet

Tags: android, android-service, default

In my application i have done all the process and they are working very well. Now my device needs only one application or other application must not come front to the user's view..

Can I make my Application as Default application or the only application viewable by the user?

To avoid the unnecessary usage of other applications or to keep time consumption I plan to try this.

Would I need to change anything in the `Manifest.xml` file of this solution solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this on a stock device. Your best bet is to create a launcher that only allows launching your app. The user needs to agree to run it however, and it can always be changed and/or disabled in Settings.